# Undefined variable, can't declare variable?

Tags: php, variables, undefined

I am getting undefined variable and I am not sure how to declare this as variable?

```
Notice: Undefined variable: [$scores_round0],
[$scores_round1],
[$scores_round2],
[$scores_final]
```

Thanks

This is function I am using:-

```
public function bracketScores($tournID) {

    $maxRounds = $this -> maxRounds($tournID);
    $scores_template = false;

    for($i = 0; $i < $maxRounds - 1; $i++) {
        $scores_template.='[$scores_round'.$i.'],<br>';
    }
    $scores_template.='[$scores_final]';

    return $scores_template;
}
```

From class file:

```
$scores_template = $_brackets -> bracketScores($tournID);
```

And from template file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">var autoCompleteData = 
{
  teams : [
    {$brackets}
  ],
  results : 
  [ 
   [ 
    {$$scores_template}
   ]
  ]
}
</script>
<div id="brackets"><div id="autoComplete"></div></div>
```

Comment: Show us the whole code

Comment: what is your code you are using.

Comment: thanks I am shared the code

Comment: `{$$scores_template}` shouldn't that be with one `$` sign?

Comment: this also a very bad way of creating JSON object. you should use `array` and `json_encode()` function in your php code to generate JSON

Comment: If I use single $ it doesn't work. I am not sure alternative way to write this.

Comment: What kind of templating engine do you use? This looks like Smarty to me

Comment: I am not sure how to use json_encode, does this mean I can't declare this as a variable?

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't come up with your own solution for outputting JSON — just use `json_encode` on an array structure:

```
function getAutoCompleteData(/* whatever params you need */) {
    // build your structure here
    $data = array(
        'teams'   => array(),
        'results' => array(),
    );

    return $data;
}
```

And then use like so:

```
<script>
var autoCompleteData = <?php echo json_encode(getAutoCompleteData(/* params */)); ?>;
</script>
```

Or for Smarty, assign the result of `getAutoCompleteData()` to a variable and use like so:

```
<script>
var autoCompleteData = {$autoCompleteData|@json_encode};
</script>
```